# Delta-V between Titan and other Saturnian moons

Tags: delta-v, saturn, titan

Does anyone have a table of the delta-V between Titan escape and other moons of Saturn? If not, could someone provide figures for Hyperion, Phoebe, Iapetus, and Enceladus? Or, more simply, what is the approximate delta-V  that would allow you to land on any other moon of Saturn (out to Phoebe) from Titan escape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made [an Excel spreadsheet](http://clowder.net/hop/TMI/HohmannGasGiantMoons-2.xls) of Saturn's moons and Jupiter's moons.

Type departure and destination moons into blue cells. Type periapsis and apoapsis of parking orbit into orange cells.

If you want to go from surface to surface, set periapsis at 0 altitude and look for Hyperbolic periapsis velocity.

Sometimes I want to look at Saturn scenarios not covered in the spreadsheet. For example Titan to Hyperion. Hyperion is not in the spreadsheet.

So I cheat. First go to Wikipedia to get Hyperion's semi major axis, mass and radius. Then put these numbers in the columns of an orbit not used much. Like LSO (Low Saturn Orbit).

[image]

Then into the blue boxes I type Titan and LSO, pretending that LSO is another name for Hyperion.

Comment: Thanks! Now to quest for a computer that has Microsoft Office...

Comment: Ah, got it to work with Google Sheets. This is awesome, thanks again!

Comment: I understand why it wasn't in the spreadsheet, but do you have a rough idea of the delta-V from Titan to Hyperion?

Comment: @Deimophobia I added to my answer what I do when I want to look at a moon not in the spreadsheet.